# Javascript Regex string between first brackets including inside brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like this

```
[test: test1: http://localhost?test=[1,2]]
[test: test2: http://localhost?test=[2,3]]
```

and I want to extract below from the text above

```
$1 = "test1"
$2 = "http://localhost?test=[1,2]"

$1 = "test2"
$2 = "http://localhost?test=[2,3]"
```

what I'm trying was

```
/\[test:(.*?):(.*?)\]/
```

but it returns like this. without "]"

```
$2 = "http://localhost?test=[2,3"
```

How can I change my regexp to get what I intented? thanks.

Comment: Using simple String functions solves this problem easier and faster. You can remove one the first and the last braces and then use `/test:(.*?):(.*?)/`. Or you can use String Split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fix to your regex would be to include the `]` in the second group:

```
/\[test:(.*?):(.*?\])\]/
// add this ------^^
```

Another fix would be to have your existing `\]` at the end of the regex only match if it is at the end of the string:

```
/\[test:(.*?):(.*?)\]$/
```

Comment: It is not working for an input `[test: test2: http://localhost?test=[2,3]&something=something]`

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev - So? That's not a format that the OP has asked about. It works for the specified input. In any case I've just added a second variation that would work.

Comment: Thanks for both of you! the second case is just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

As I guess, you get an URL as a second parameter. 
It will be really not pretty easy to make a correct regex which will include all possible URL values.

```
[test: test1: http://localhost?test=[1,2]]
[test: test1: http://localhost?test=[1,2]&somekey=somevalue]
[test: test1: http://localhost?test=[1,2]&answers=[1,2,3]]
```

You tried to find such regexp yourself. You came here, asked this question and spend so much of your expensive time trying to find a proper regular expression.
And even if you now find such regular expression, did you really need it?

As a popular quote says:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions."
>   Now they have two problems.

It is up to your choice, I can only recommend but there is an **easy**, **fast** way which works with **any** data given in an input:

```
var str = "[test: test1: http://localhost?test=[1,2]]";
str = str.substring(1, str.length - 1);

var vals = str.split(': ');

console.log(vals[1]);
console.log(vals[2]);
```

No regular expressions, no headache. I don't want to say "don't use regex", I want to say "don't use it when it is not required" :)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I also considered not to using regex, because I'm not used to it... but In my case, the example string is inside other massive text, so I cannot use split.